# Large size Image or multiple images uploading is working properly in mozilla, but not working in chrome. Giving "504 Gateway Timeout" error

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter

**Script is in codeigniter**

**Front End: Angular, Back End: Codeigniter**

**Large size Image or multiple images uploading is working properly in mozilla, but not working in chrome. Giving "504 Gateway Timeout" error**

When I am trying to upload large size images **in chrome** its giving "**504 Gateway Timeout" error**"

Working fine in mozilla..

**php.ini file code:**

```
memory_limit=-1
upload_max_filesize=500M
post_max_size=500M
max_execution_time=200
display_errors=On
date.timezone=Europe/London
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
session.save_path="/tmp"
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
```

**Also tried with:**

```
memory_limit=-1
upload_max_filesize=2000M
post_max_size=2000M
max_execution_time=1000
display_errors=On
date.timezone=Europe/London
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
session.save_path="/tmp"
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
```

But same issue....

**There is no error in uploading script**

Please suggest me changes or ideas.

Comment: Isn't your question contradicting `working properly in mozilla, but not working in mozilla`??

Comment: corrected @ngShravil.py please suggest me changes to solve this

Comment: Try changing apache/nginx timeouts, just in case.

Comment: @David where I can change it.. please guide me